# Опять проблема с "не"

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-не

Ну как нам справиться с неграмотностью прессы? Вот цитатка с сайта (его редактирует писатель!): "все страны, не зависимо от того, бедные они или". Мне кажется, что "не" тут должно быть слитно. Но может быть, есть новые веяния?

Comment: wik, здесь принято задавать конкретные вопросы, а не стенать по поводу общей неграмотности.

Comment: Ничего удивительного, если редактировал не редактор, а писатель.

Comment: @Alex_ander да помилуйте. Во-первых писатели бывают пограмотнее иных редакторов, который набор инструкций давно мозги заменил. А во-вторых, кто там будет редактировать материал для непойми какого сайта? Хорошо если сознательный автор сам свой текст вычитает. А так - обычное дело: ворд красненьким не подчеркнул - погнали.

Comment: Согласен, именно "бывают" и "иных".

Comment: Иногда слитное и раздельное написание "не" очень даже влияет на смысл. Классический пример: гражданином Непала является тот, кто рождён непальцем и непалкой".

Answer (score 4):

"Все страны, **независимо от того**, бедные они или".  Это составной предлог со слитным написанием.

Из словаря:

**НЕЗАВИСИМО**, **нареч**. к Независимый (1 зн.). Держаться смело и независимо. <**Независимо от кого-чего**, в зн. **предлога**. Несмотря на что-л., не принимая во внимание кого-, что-л. Уйти из института независимо от желания отца. Действовать независимо от остальных. **Независимо от того что**, в зн. **союза**. Несмотря на то что; хотя. Явился на работу, независимо от того что был болен.

**Примечание**

"Независимый"  является прилагательным и в большинстве случаев пишется слитно. Исключением являются усилительные отрицательные конструкции, но и среди них иногда встречается слитное написание, например:

Мы хотим иметь свой, **не зависимый ни от кого** театр. [Виктор Розов. Удивление перед жизнью (1960-2000)]

Посол Резанов, уполномоченный заключить торговый союз с Японией, должен был также еще «приобрести остров Сахалин, **не зависимый ни от китайцев, ни от японцев»**. [А. П. Чехов. Остров Сахалин (1893-1895)

Этот титул говорит, что Россия ― народ державный, **независимый ни от кого на свете,** никому не подчиненный. [М. О. Меньшиков. Русское пробуждение (1910.01.23)]

А вот современный текст: **Независимый ни от кого** профсоюз отчитался перед Аксеновым.

Чаще раздельная форма встречается в обособленных оборотах, где выбор по смыслу (утверждение или отрицание) кажется более обоснованным.

Answer (score 0):

Значит, по поводу сайта и писателя.
Лучше всего здесь таких пассажей не делать. А если уж невмоготу, то называйте четко и ясно источник.
По вашему отрывку понять наверняка даже нельзя, возможно там раздельное написание или нет.

Сайт, надо понимать этот.
http://svpressa.ru/economy/article/155915/

Кто его издает и какие-такие писатели редактируют, Истории неизвестно.
Сильно сомневаюсь, что этот текст вычитал кто-то кроме автора и вас. 
Значит, к автору и все претензии. Да, общий уровень грамотности в интернет-текстах упал, но возмущаться этим нет смысла, этот текст совсем не худший вариант.

Что касается раздельного написания, это здесь это может быть и не ошибка даже, а законное отрицание: **не являющийся зависимым**.

Хотя трудно предположить, что здесь такое, но формально может иметь место. В целом же текст весьма грамотный, вряд ли автор не знает правила... Так что скорее всего элементарный технический брак при наборе или верстке.